# cross browser compatibility issues with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: cross-browser

In mozilla firefox there is an option to switch browser through "switch rendering engine", and it comes only if i have an "IE Tab2 Add-On" installed and enabled in Mozilla. If i run my application, browser should automatically detect the "URL" of my application and add it to filtered sites, and switch it to IE mode . I want this to happen so that I can run my application in Mozilla Firefox, but since i developed it in IE now it is showing many compatibility issues in firefox. And i also want to download IE add-on if it not already present in Mozilla

Comment: What are you asking exactly? its not clear

Comment: @ nrathaus In mozilla firefox there is an option to switch browser through "switch rendering engine", and it comes only if i have an "IE Tab2 Add-On" installed and enabled in Mozilla. If i run my application, browser should automatically detect the "URL" of my application and add it to filtered sites, and switch it to IE mode

Comment: Poor users... Not sure about detecting this add-on but you definetely can't silently download and install add-ons.